# Yii2 DynamicForm Input File Image always empty or NULL

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions

I'm using wbraganca yii2-dynamicform and kartik yii2-widget-fileinput. The form works fine but when I'm trying the getinstance for upload the images always is null.

This is my controller.

```php
public function addMultipleImage($model){
       $modelsOptionValue = Model::createMultiple(OptionValue::classname());
        Model::loadMultiple($modelsOptionValue, Yii::$app->request->post());
        foreach ($modelsOptionValue as $index => $modelOptionValue) {
            $modelOptionValue->sort_order = $index;
            $file[$index]=  UploadedFile::getInstanceByName("OptionValue[".$index."][upload_image]");
            var_dump($file[$index]);
          if($file[$index]){
                $ext = end((explode(".", $file[$index]->name)));
                // generate a unique file name
                $modelOptionValue->img= Yii::$app->security->generateRandomString().".{$ext}";
                $path[$index]= Yii::getAlias ('@web') ."/img/". $modelOptionValue->img;
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }
```

View form

```php
  //_form.php
  <?php $form = ActiveForm::begin( [
    'enableClientValidation' => false,
    'enableAjaxValidation' => true,
    'validateOnChange' => true,
    'validateOnBlur' => false,
    'options' => [
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
        'id' => 'dynamic-form'
    ] 
    ]);
?>
  //_form_add_image.php
 <?php DynamicFormWidget::begin([
    'widgetContainer' => 'dynamicform_wrapper',
    'widgetBody' => '.form-options-body',
    'widgetItem' => '.form-options-item',
    'min' => 1,
    'insertButton' => '.add-item',
    'deleteButton' => '.delete-item',
    'model' => $modelsOptionValue[0],
    'formId' => 'dynamic-form',
    'formFields' => [
        'upload_image'
    ],
]); ?>

 <?= $form->field($modelOptionValue, "[{$index}]upload_image")->label(false)->widget(FileInput::classname(), [
                        'options' => [
                            'multiple' => false,
                            'accept' => 'image/*',
                            'class' => 'optionvalue-img'
                        ],
                        'pluginOptions' => [
                            'previewFileType' => 'image',
                            'showCaption' => false,
                            'showUpload' => false,
                            'browseClass' => 'btn btn-default btn-sm',
                            'browseLabel' => ' Seleccionar Imagen',
                            'browseIcon' => '<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture"></i>',
                            'removeClass' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm',
                            'removeLabel' => ' Borrar',
                            'removeIcon' => '<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>',
                            'previewSettings' => [
                                'image' => ['width' => '138px', 'height' => 'auto']
                            ],
                            'initialPreview' => $initialPreview,
                            'layoutTemplates' => ['footer' => '']
                        ]
                    ]) ?>
```

and my model

```php
public $upload_image;
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public static function tableName()
{
    return 'option_value';
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['upload_image'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg', 'skipOnEmpty' => true],
        [['id_montacarga', 'sort_order'], 'integer']
    ];
}
```

screenshot of yii2 log. updated

[image: yiilog]

inspect element screenshot
[image: html]

Thanks!!!

Comment: add `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'`.

Comment: @InsaneSkull thanks for the answer,  where ? inside in options or pluginOptions?

Comment: try inside `options` . Refer: http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo2/source-code

Comment: @InsaneSkull Thanks just forgot to add  the params in ActiveForm::begin(). I just update my question. And now i got empty in image.

Comment: @insaneSkull Just i remove the ajax options. And finally works. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'` in `ActiveForm`.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'options' => [
        'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
         'id' => 'dynamic-form'
    ]
]); ?>
```

Set Ajax Validation to false if you don't want ajax validation.

[Reference](http://wbraganca.com/yii2extensions/dynamicform-demo2/source-code)